# Collecting Rainwater off a Domestic Roof for Flushing Toilets

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, mechanical

I am working on a project for an Environmental Engineering class. Our concept is a system that collects rain water for use in toilet flushing, i.e. requires minimal filtration. I have no experience in engineering statics, so I am curious if it is possible, with calculations to back it up, to attach a 50 gallon drum for water collection to the side of a house for purposes of gravity feeding the water into a toilet on a lower level of the house. And if not, could this be accomplished at low cost with the rain barrel instead at ground level, collecting runoff from the rain gutters on the roof, using a water pump to displace the water to the bathroom? Any help is appreciated thank you :D 
Additional details: we are students at the University of Washington, so our system is initially proposed for rainy cities such as Seattle where collecting large volumes of rainwater is fairly easy, and the availability of the rainwater isn't of much concern. This solution intends to solve problems off runoff, and to lower monthly water utility cost, as well as to save on water usage.

Comment: Is there a specific engineering problem you are trying to solve or are you asking about feasibility?

Comment: It’s being done already : do your research, oh and one problem was pine needles coloring the water to make it look like piss...

Comment: You should think about the amount of water needed for a toilet : number of flushes per day : big or small flushes : how many times one person flushes : number of people in dwelling etc  then you can consider the size of storage - more than 50 gallons !!!

Comment: As @SolarMike states there's nothing new in this. I know people who did this 12 years ago! The only difference was their water tank capacity was at least 5000 liters.They used a ground based tank & a pump. If the water is only going to be used for the toilet it is even possible to have the system store waste water from laundry. Again, something that was achieved more than a decade ago. If you go to the right people they can have system designed & installed very quickly - it's almost mainstream.

Comment: One example I can think of dates back to the late 1970's... and still in use now , but updated, no pump - isn't gravity a wonderful thing...

Comment: @Solar Mike Can you provide this particular example: sources or links etc?

Comment: @Donald Gibson I am primarily asking about feasibility, I.e. if this could be engineered

Comment: @Fred can you provide sources/links ?

Comment: @Divine1 any research should give you this as an example, they have been around since the 70's.... I have given you sufficient hints so good luck.

Comment: Google "greywater harvesting" if you want to do more research into existing systems.

Comment: Some links for rainwater harvesting & using the water for toilets. Note, the plumbing for such systems needs to be physically separate from the town water supply system to prevent contamination of the town water supply. [San Diego City](https://www.sandiego.gov/water/conservation/rainwater), [Ref 2](http://www.phoenixsailingcharters.com/rainwater.htm) & [Ref 3](http://www.reuk.co.uk/wordpress/water/rainwater-toilet-flush-system/)

Comment: I am voting to close this as too broad because [we are not a homework completion service.](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/122/368)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 8 pounds a gallon, a 50 gallon drum when full will weigh 400 pounds. This load cannot safely be fastened to the side of a house which was not designed to carry it. You will require a separate pedestal to support the weight of the drum, and it will need to be anchored in place so it will not tip over in an earthquake. If, on the other hand, you position the drum at ground level, you do not have to worry about the effect the drum's weight would have on your house and it does not have to be earthquake-proof. A simple pump can then be used to move the water where you want it.

Note that in tropical locations that get a lot of rain, it is common to design the roof of a house to support a rainwater catchment tank that can hold hundreds of gallons of water for toilet flushing. I think your idea is worth pursuing but  ideally you want the house to be designed from scratch to accomodate your design.  Good luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

You should evaluate the source : ie amount of rainfall over the year, when it is available, how many days it rains etc.

Then evaluate the use over the year : flushes per day etc.

Then you can work out the storage volume necessary based on the number of days between rainfall filling the tank and the use per day.

Once you have the volume of tank required then you can work out the weight and start designing a support or decide where it can be located (my parents house had the water tank halfway up the hill to provide pressure with no pumps necessary...).

Comment: We are primarily designing for a more urban setting, without lots of land. I have worked out a lot of the details, ideally the water could even be used for other purposes as well if properly filtered and tested, even offsetting almost all water use for a household (it rains 37 inches per year here on average). In a best case scenario a 250gal plus tank would be best but pairing down to 50 gal would be more feasible for cheap, low cost of entry, and more likely to be able to add to an existing structure in some way as niels nielsen mentioned with a pedastal or some other contraption.